How do I restore screen dimming without restart?
This is 24.10 but the problem has existed for many prior releases.
I want timed screen dimming to WORK. I know how to set this up under Settings->Power Saving->Screen Blank (I usually have it set to 10 minutes). It works fine until it doesn't. I have no idea what is causing it to stop working and the only way to fix it seems to be to do a restart. Any idea what is disabling screen dimming? Some web page? If so, how do I find out which one? And how do I fix it without having to do a restart? It's amusing that all the "similar questions" are the exact opposite of my problem!
